# Azure automl time series forecasting error

Tags: time-series, dataset, forecasting, azure-ml, automl

I'm using [Microsoft Azure automl](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/) to try and generate models for time series forecasting but I keep getting an error:

```
Error: Could not determine the data set time frequency. All series in the data set have one row and no freq parameter was provided. Please provide the freq (forecast frequency) parameter or review the time_series_id_column_names setting to decrease the number of time series.
```

My data set looks like:

```
          Date,       Temp,
1,2019-05-07 13:51:00,25.19,
2,2019-05-07 13:51:58,25.14,
3,2019-05-07 13:53:00,25.14,
4,2019-05-07 13:54:00,25.14,
5,2019-05-07 13:55:00,25.1,
6,2019-05-07 13:55:58,25.1,
7,2019-05-07 13:57:00,25.1,
8,2019-05-07 13:57:58,25.11,
9,2019-05-07 13:58:58,25.11,
10,2019-05-07 14:00:00,25.07,
11,2019-05-07 14:01:00,25.07,
12,2019-05-07 14:02:00,23.11,
```

I followed the steps on the [ml.azure.com](https://ml.azure.com/) gui, I don't see a place for `freq` or `time_series_id_column_names`

Seems to be an issue with the data set, any ideas on how I can prevent/fix this error would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data either has duplicates or you may have some rows with empty values. I removed my rows at the bottom that had empty values separated by comma which resolved the issue

Comment: Thanks so much!